# How to record logs with NLog .NET Core 6

Tags: logging, nlog

I am using NLog for logging my app, I only followed an example from the documentation but I can't understand some things, such as, what is the "logger" property for within the rules section? currently has the values ​​"controllers and repositories"

[image]

The other problem I have is that when I execute the instruction _logger.LogInfo("any log") or _logger.LogInformation("any log") neither of these are recorded in my log file, what am I doing wrong? I leave you an example

Program.cs (load nlog)

```
LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("NLog"));

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddNLog();
```

then when I want to use the log in different layers:

Controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RequestFilter filter)
{

    _logger.LogInformation("log test......."); //not work
    _logger.LogDebug("log debug test......."); //not work
    _logger.LogError("log error test......."); //not work

    //code.....

    return Ok("success");
 }
```

The log file is generated but it does not record any log that I save throughout my application

log result in text file:

> 2023-11-21 12:11:43.2474 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
> 2023-11-21 12:11:43.3100 Info Registered target
> NLog.Targets.FileTarget(Name=file) 2023-11-21 12:11:43.3286 Info
> Validating config: TargetNames=file, ConfigItems=19 ConfigSection=NLog
> 2023-11-21 12:12:35.7331 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
> 2023-11-21 12:12:35.8335 Info Registered target
> NLog.Targets.FileTarget(Name=file) 2023-11-21 12:12:35.8638 Info
> Validating config: TargetNames=file, ConfigItems=19 ConfigSection=NLog
> 2023-11-21 12:13:40.4712 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
> 2023-11-21 12:13:40.5965 Info Registered target
> NLog.Targets.FileTarget(Name=file) 2023-11-21 12:13:40.6250 Info
> Validating config: TargetNames=file, ConfigItems=19 ConfigSection=NLog
> 2023-11-21 17:14:56.1217 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
> 2023-11-21 17:14:56.4649 Info Registered target
> NLog.Targets.FileTarget(Name=file) 2023-11-21 17:14:56.4834 Info
> Validating config: TargetNames=file, ConfigItems=19 ConfigSection=NLog
> 2023-11-21 17:14:56.8172 Info Validating config: TargetNames=file,
> ConfigItems=19 ConfigSection=NLog

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand the existing [logging-rules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules), then just replace it with this:

```json
{
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "internalLogFile": "${basedir}/logs/logs-nlog.txt",
    "targets": {
      "file": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/my_api-log-${shortdate}.log",
        "maxArchiveFiles": 7
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "file"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Notice the `log result in text file:` is the output from the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to `logs/logs-nlog.txt`, and not the output from your application-logfile `logs/my_api-log`. Notice [${basedir}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Basedir-layout-renderer) is the default root when using relative-path in `"fileName"`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#filename-directory